# What is the alternative for PathOverlay in MapBox?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, mapbox, pubnub

I am building a real-time location-sharing Android application using PubNub.
I was following [one of their tutorials](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/android-mapping-geolocation-tracking/) using Google Maps and they had an [extension on using MapBox](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/publishing-realtime-location-with-the-android-mapbox-api/).

Personally, I was leaning more toward MapBox for their generous free tier.
Sadly most of the methods and classes are deprecated by now and I'm not advanced enough to understand MapBox docs.

I have Markers and PathOverLay both not found and the same MapView.
I am using the latest SDK version of Mapbox

```java
        private void initializePolyline() {
            mMapView.removeOverlay(mLine);
            mMapView.clear();
            mLine = new PathOverlay(Color.BLUE, 5);
        }
    
        private void updatePolyline() {
            mMapView.removeOverlay(mLine);
            mLine.addPoint(mLatLng);
            mMapView.getOverlays().add(mLine);
        }
    
        private void updateCamera() {
            mMapView.setCameraDistance(10);
            mMapView.setCenter(mLatLng);
        }
    
        private void updateMarker() {
            if (!isFirstMessage) {
                mMapView.removeMarker(mMarker);
            }
            isFirstMessage = false;
            mMarker = new Marker(mMapView, "", "", mLatLng);
            mMapView.addMarker(mMarker);
        }
    }
```

This is a snippet from `MBoxShareLocationActivity.java`
Here is the [link](https://assets.ctfassets.net/3prze68gbwl1/asset-17suaysk1qa1hwm/0201e264e4b4382b6c49b15c49cb0ba5/Android-Location-Application.zip) for the source code provided alongside the tutorial.

Deprecated classes : `Markers`, `PathOverlay` not found, `GoogleApiClient`, `LocationServices`, `FusedLocationApi`

Comment: This blog/tutorial is from May 2015, so understandably outdated. The only real answer is that you need to make the code changes to use the latest version of Google Maps or Mapbox. Have you reached out to Mapbox support for assistance? You will also want to upgrade to the [latest PubNub Java SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/java/) which is not much different (maybe no code changes required) than the current version.

Comment: I would recommend just starting from scratch with [PubNub Android SDK Getting Started](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/quickstarts/android) and add in the latest Mapbox library using the old tutorials as a guide.

Comment: Yeah i will definitely do that.PubNub's documentations are very clear unlike Mapbox. And apparently, Google Maps API is free for android devices. Thank you